# Can't clear my notification email address

Tags: feature-request, bug

I like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286967/identicon-changes-unexpectedly) behaviour for a number of reasons, however I'm stuck with my current email.

When I try to unset it:

[image]

the button fades and exactly the same XHR request (with exactly the same response) is made:

[image]

But the email is there after the page reload.

I've found a few related questions, e.g. [E-Mail Preferences Act Very Stubbornly!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297941/2301450).

Is it possible to make my email empty? If no, can this be allowed? Please tell me I don't have to verify the ‹empty string› email... :(